Custom ESP32-S3 board usb disconnect and reconnect every second
I connect esp32 s3 wroom board to pc windows 10. I hear usb connect noise than 1 or 2 seconds later it disconnects this repeats so it is constantly connecting and disconnecting. I held reset button before powering and after powering didn't effect it. Arduino detects board correctly and works for 1 second it is connected. It is definitely being detected by usb.
DATASHEET - https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-s3-wroom-1_wroom-1u_datasheet_en.pdf
1.) Why is usb disconnecting and reconnecting every second.
2.) How do  I fix this.

Schematic I used

How does the voltage on VIN look with an oscilloscope?

Please update your schematics (in a comment you said that this is outdated). Also, check out this guide on how to draw good schematics.

This schematic is outdated but is the one I actually have built and need solution for

C18//C22 will put you above Vbus max capacitance allowed for USB.

easy: hold down the flash button while plugging in to enter program mode instead of execution mode. Once you put the first program on, it will stop cycling. It doesn't have anything to do with power consumption.

Your battery charger is pulling 1A without asking the PC if that's OK.
USB ports are not allowed to pull 1A.
The max current that can be negotiated is only 500mA.
And you can't pull 500mA without negotiation, if there is less than that available.
According to specs, you are allowed to pull 100mA, and more when PC tells your device that the amout it requests is available.

Yes i am aware and i fixed that sorry this was old before i fixed that, It wont effect this because battery is not connected to board yet, i was doing this only using usb micro as it works without battery, So it not charging or using battery as battery is not even connected
